# Android implicit BroadcastReceiver with signature permission is not called in Android O

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-implicit-intent

In my first application, I define a custom permission and an implicit `BroadcastReceiver` in manifest file:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.test.TEST"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<receiver
        android:name=".TestBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.example.test.TEST">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.test.TEST_RECEIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And this is the TestBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class TestBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("Test", "Hello World!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

In my second app, I've added the permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.TEST" />
```

And here, I send the broadcast:

```
getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.test.TEST_RECEIVER"));
```

But nothing is called in first app. I know we can't use implicit broadcast in android O and above but according to [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts), there is an exception for broadcasts that require a signature permission:

> Broadcasts that require a signature permission are exempted from this
> restriction, since these broadcasts are only sent to apps that are
> signed with the same certificate, not to all the apps on the device.

So how can I signal my other apps in android O?

Comment: Since this is all in your own app, use an explicit `Intent`. Also note that you need to guarantee that your first app is *always* installed before the second app for a `signature` permission to be effective.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I replaced the intent with `new Intent("com.example.test.TestBroadcastReceiver").setPackage("com.example.test")`, But problem still exists.

Comment: Your revised `Intent` action does not match the action string in your `<intent-filter>`. Either use your original `Intent` action plus the `setPackage("com.example.test")` part, or use `new Intent(context, TestBroadcastReceiver.class)` (if `TestBroadcastReceiver` is in the same app as the broadcast sender).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CommonsWare answer, the problem is that I was missing `setPackage()` part. So I changed the code as below and now broadcast is received:

```
getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.test.TEST_RECEIVER").setPackage("com.example.test"));
```